# UI TextField acts as search and update to TableView

Tags: ios, swift

In the main UI, i have the UI TextField and TableView. The table view shows the list of my items. Right of the UI TextField will have add icon. 
The scenario is 
 1. User enter on TextFiled, it will try to search of the available list items and show the search result in table view. 
 2. If the search result is empty, the user can choose to add the item to the list.

I will not use the searchbar. But i would like to implement like the behavior of the searchbar. Although UI search bar and search display controller is deprecated in ios 8, i would like to know how it is implemented.

Currently i am adding the

```
@IBAction func textEditChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    println("textEditChanged:\(sender.text)")
}
```

when there is text changed, then i would like to reload tableview with search result.

In the searchDisplayController, it has its own TableView to display search result. So in the main UI controller we need to show like below:

```
 if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
   // Add what we want to show
  }
else {
  // original table view in the UIViewController
 }

 func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
        return true
    }
```

searchDisplayyController needs to return true to reload the tableview.

I hope the TextField can have such controller, searchResultTableView and can reload the tableview like above.

Can someone guide me how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, it seems that you want to reload your data manually but you are using a UISearchController. UISearchController is a helper to filter your data and reload your tableview, you don't need it if you want to do it all manually. Is this what you want ?

Comment: UISearchBar is not deprecated in iOS 8 only UISearchDisplayController(deprecates in iOS 8):  refer this ..https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/

Comment: Justa , i won't use UISearchBar. I want to do it myself. But i would like to know the design of UISearchBar and UISearchBarController. It has its own tableview and update search result. 

Currently what i do is quite naive. I only have one tableview and i use a flag to determine in search mode or not and fill the tableview with the content

But i want two tableviews: one tableview without in search mode and one tableview with search mode. I would like to know how to do it more elegantly like search Controller update search result.